# "Kiosk Mode" in PWA on Android?

Tags: android, web, progressive-web-apps, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm creating a PWA site  and I have a task to hide virtual buttons and android's status bar when the PWA application is open, so that there is no way to exit the application except with the built-in "Exit" button.

I found quite an old resource about "kiosk_enabled" and "kiosk_only" in manifest.json but it doesn't work in the current (85) version of Google chrome (status bar and virtual buttons are not hidden).

> developers.google.com/web/shows/google-io/2014/unleash-the-power-of-kiosk-apps

Is this functionality still working , and if so, how can I properly enable it in PWA?

Comment: I don't think you can. If they enabled that, someone could easily build a malicious app from which the user could not exit unless they re-boot their phone.

Comment: On desktop PWA and android apps this feature works, so it seems to me that it is also possible on mobile PWA

Comment: Setting "display": "fullscreen" in the manifest hides the virtual buttons and status bar.  You would have to somehow disable the drag gesture to stop users accessing them completely.